# I'm new to arch linux can't connect to wifi

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwd

After installation I used `iwctl` to connect wifi. It say me 'stat connected' and 'connected network to the wifi box'. I'm exiting and when I type `ping google.com` it say me `Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: First check if your WiFi card ha an IP by issuing `ip a`: under your card name there should be some ipv4 entry. Please edit your question with the output of this command if you need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to connect to a protected WiFi network on Archlinux is to run `sudo wifi-menu` and follow it's instructions. Then, by issuing `sudo netctl list` you should see a `*` on the left of the active connection. Use then `sudo netctl start/enable <connection_name>` to either instantly start the connection or enable it at each system boot.